# How to use only the default git port with gitorious.org

Tags: git, gitorious

Assuming I can telnet to gitorious.org port 9418 (default for git), but not on SSH port. How to set up gitorious so that when I try to push, this wouldn't happen:

```
git push
ssh: connect to host gitorious.org port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

So I want to use ONLY port 9418. Is that possible and how to do it?

Comment: What does your .git/config look like?

Comment: atm there is only user information and http proxy server given

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Port 9418 is the default port for the git protocol, which is unauthenticated, unencrypted, and therefore meant to be read-only. Unless gitorious is doing something weird (I doubt it), all you can do on that port is read (fetch/pull).

The primary workaround if SSH is blocked is to use HTTPS - can you push that way?

Comment: git push https://gitorious.org/path/to/project.git -> error: SSL: certificate subject name (*.gitorious.org) does not match target host name 'gitorious.org' while accessing https://gitorious.org/path/to/project.git/info/refs. fatal: HTTP request failed. (I have added SSH keys)

Comment: @user: I'm assuming SSH is blocked by a firewall on your side, which is why I suggested HTTPS might work. (You would have gotten publickey authentication errors if your keys weren't set up, not a timeout.) I don't know if gitorious supports HTTPS pushing; that's why I phrased that as a question. It's really up to you to see what push mechanisms your hosting provider supports, and try them.

Comment: If you are able to use the SSL port (443) through your firewall, you could push via SSH on this port using the host name ssh.gitorious.org. Please note that this is in fact SSH over a non-standard port, not SSL/HTTPS. So the SSH command would be `ssh -p 443 git@ssh.gitorious.org`

Comment: I think pushing to gitorious via https does not work, at least did not work for me

Answer (score 1):

The `.git/config` has an `[remote "origin"] -> url` that can follow one of the following patterns:

```
ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/

git://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/

http[s]://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/

ftp[s]://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/

rsync://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/
```

Based on the error you're providing, it looks like your's points to `ssh://`. If you want to push through 9418, and if gitorious supports it, (git:// protocol's default port), you'll need the origin to point to that.